# NSFetchedResultsController with predefined number of rows per section

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using NSFetchedResultsController to fetch the data from core data and load the content in UITableView. I need to show data in tableView with sections and each section should show predefined rows.

Let's say I'm having Company and Employee table with one to may relationship from company to employee. I want to restrict the number of employee to be displayed depends on company. Please find the model graph

[image]

Below is the one of the out come which i am looking for.

CompanyA - 5 Employees

CompanyB - 10 Employees

CompanyC - 10 Employees

CompanyD - 15 Employees
....so on

Below code I am using to get the records from core data,

```
NSFetchRequest *fetch = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Employee" inManagedObjectContext:moc];

NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"employeeID IN %@", employeeIDs];
fetch.predicate = pred;

NSSortDescriptor *sortTime = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"employeeID" ascending:YES];

fetch.sortDescriptors = @[sortTime, sortGroup];

NSFetchedResultsController *controller = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetch
                                                                             managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                               sectionNameKeyPath:@"company.companyID"
                                                                                        cacheName:nil];
```

I found "**fetchLimit**" property of NSFetchRequest, but this property restrict the total fetched record.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can just return the number you want in `tableView:numberOfRowsInSction:` for each section

Comment: @EricQian By doing this the nsfetchedresultscontroller delegate methods fails to update tableView when any update happens in core data

Comment: Manually sort out those updates in the delegate methods for example if you receive an insert object in section 1, however the rows in section 1 have hit the limit, then just do nothing in the delegate method.